# Custom highlight UIView

Tags: ios

I custom View extend UIView

```
@interface AttachmentView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, getter=isHighlighted) BOOL highlighted;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageFileType;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbSize;

- (void)initComponent;

@end
```

i override method

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    if(highlighted) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

But when i touch on view, method `setHighlighted` not call, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

UIView don't like "UILabel and UIImageView" which have highlighted state.

You should do it by yourself in `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.highlighted = !self.highlighted ;
}
```

Or add `UITapGestureRecognizer` or `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`(if you want detect long pressed gesture) to the view.

Comment: I create custom UIView subview UITableViewCell, setHighlighted called.

Comment: @NhuNguyen What do you mean "create custom UIView subview UITableViewCell"?

Comment: No, i custom view subview for UIWebView, but i custom view subview UITableViewCell method call, but for UIWebView method setHighlighted not call.

Comment: @NhuNguyen UITableViewCell has highlighted state, and when its highlighted property is changed, it may using `subview responderToSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:)` to judge whether its subview has the method, if it has, it would send the message to the selector. UITableViewCell do this because it need all subview to reflect highlighted state automatically.

Comment: @NhuNguyen I have tested it. If you change the `highlighted` property, `UITableViewCell` won't send `setHighlighted:` message to its subviews. If you touch the cell, it will send the message to its subviews.